# Cross domain restrictions and subdomains

Tags: cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

Is there a cross domain policy restriction for subdomains?

If I have an application on `paint.xxxx.com` which is manipulating images from `image.xxxx.com`, are there any cross domain problems?

I'm asking these questions, because I'm considering putting a proxy on a subdomain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes the cross domain restriction applies for subdomains.

The solution is to put

document.domain = "example.com" ; // whatever your domain name is

in the top of the js file(s) for both the parent domain and the child domain

Google Document.domain and cross site and there should be a better explanation but I've had the same issue and that is what worked for me.

Comment: this is valid only for iframes using subdomain, where the security rules are relaxed. check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules