# FontAwesome doesn't display in Firefox

Tags: firefox, font-awesome

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638476/font-awesome-not-displaying-properly-on-firefox).

Boris' answer to the above question seems to make sense, but I installed the Font Awesome files on my server and the problem remains:

[image]

I looked into the library and found that the font files are included in the install, so the argument about cross-server access to fonts doesn't seem valid. I don't mind using the BootstrapCDN, but then Boris' suggestion seems to apply, and I don't know how to send the right CORS headers. (I tried it, but it doesn't work either.) Any idea how I can fix this, either using the "Bootstrap CDN" or the "default CSS"? (see also [these instructions](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/).)

---

PS: IE10 shows the glyph correctly.

Comment: I had the same problem than i looked at the debugger in firefox , it seems that there is some cross origin issue .

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource"

So make sure that you are requesting font files from the same path including http ://www. n/or simple http :// :

So if website address is http ://domain.tld you must include css src from the same path so the fonts can be correctly accessed by the browser . 

I hope this helps !

Comment: Nicely explained here: http://code-epicenter.com/font-awesome-is-not-showingworking-in-mozilla-firefox/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Did you try Bootstrap CDN?

Just include `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">` in your `<head>` section. Font files will be loaded automatically from CDN, too.

Checked this on Firefox and it works perfectly.

@Boris says:

> Firefox only allows cross-domain linking of fonts if **the server the font is on** sends the right CORS headers.

So it's clear that it's **CDNs duty** to set the right headers, **not yours**. And them seem to do that correctly, because Firefox doesn't complain.

If you host fonts on your own server, keep in mind that cross-domain rule may still apply, e.g. font files places under `example.com` may be unaccessible from `www.example.com`, if `www.example.com` doesn't send the right headers.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640461/cross-domain-restrictions-and-sub-domain) for tips about bypassing cross-sub-domain restrictions - this might help in your case.

Comment: Yes, I tried Bootstrap CDN, but that didn't work either. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Can you post a link to your website?

Comment: [this page](http://zorl.net/fa_cdn.php) is stripped to the bare essentials and uses the Bootstrap CDN. Doesn't work. Apparently, when I do the same for the [locally installed FA](http://zorl.net/fa_local.php), it *does* work.

Comment: [This page](http://zorl.net/index_fa.php) shows the (big) icon correctly, while [this page](http://www.zorl.net/indext.php) doesn't. Note that the contents of both pages are **identical**. I already cleared Firefox' cache, but no avail...

Comment: For me (Firefox 21.0, Linux) [CDN version](http://zorl.net/fa_cdn.php) works perfectly. Three other links (installed locally) work only **without "www." prefix** - I mean http://zorl.net/index_fa.php works, but http://www.zorl.net/index_fa.php **doesn't**. I think this is the right direction to dig, maybe you should ask another question?

Comment: Michal, the www subdomain seems to be the culprit. So "cross-domain" seems to include subdomains too. If you add it to your answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This issue also caused our FontAwesome icons to not render in FireFox. They did work Using the CDN (which sent the correct headers)

Comment: This CDN worked for me - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: https://wpvkp.com/font-awesome-doesnt-display-in-firefox-maxcdn/  this link explains how to get it working on a server

Answer (score 1):

Put in a custom CSS the following (for me it solved the problem):

```css
@font-face
{
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  src:url('./fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src:url('./fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('./fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('./fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('./fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before
{
  font-family:FontAwesome;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:inherit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of your own server, you can add a HTTP header to deal with that problem. Problem based on cross domain policies.

`example.com/font-awesome.woff`

`boo.example/index.htm`

in that case you should add that header to `example.com`

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "http://boo.example"
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

that will make your font file reachable from other sites or specific site.

Comment: if both font and page are served from same server (according to OP), how is it related to cross-origin?

Comment: In this case server is an abstract concept; they both can be served on same IP or web server but it does not make them tied. Consider a hosting company serving many domains. I would not want my domain reachable by others on the same IP. Domain level restriction is a standard. Only sub-domains can be exceptions to some extend.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same issue, we use the fonts on router board using micro httpd.
i added Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header but not working for me.

i found in firebug that the woff file is not returing anything in response text. the same thing if i use CDN url, everything works fine. so on local micro-httpd server need some mandatory header to configure. please tell me also the exact mime types for all fonts needed.

- .ttf", "application/x-font-ttf"
- .eot", "application/vnd.ms-fontobject"
- .woff", "application/font-woff"
- .svg", "image/svg+xml"

Answer (score 0):

solution to make the fontawesome css work locally is to include the files under Fonts folder into the same directory of  .html files(pages).

eg:File structure as of now where fontawesome is not working

```
    prototype\pages\.html files
    prototype\styles\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.min.css
    prototype\styles\font-awesome\css\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot,fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

The issue here is that for a page loaded from a file:// URI, only files in (or below) the same directory of the filesystem are considered to be "same origin", and so putting the font in a different subtree (../font/) means it will be blocked by security policy restrictions.As Firefox disables cross-domain fonts "by default.
Instead change the file structure as below:

```
      prototype\pages\.html files
      prototype\styles\font-awesome\css\font-awesome.min.css
     prototype\pages\fonts\fontawesome-webfont.eot,fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

place the fonts folder under pages directory which fixes the issue.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
some-class-name:before
{
  content: attr(\f021);
}
```

worked for me

Answer (score -11):

Be sure your paths are correct. Use the fa class and the icon class like:

*fa fa-envelope*

and will work great..

Greetings.

Comment: He clearly is already doing that, or it wouldn't show up on other browsers than Firefox...