# Using icon font (Fontawesome) in HTML select

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, forms

I'd like to show icons from the Fontawesome font in an HTML select. I'm using this CSS for the select:

```
select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', Arial;
}
```

**EDIT**: Here is the HTML for the select:

```
<select>
  <option value="2">&#xf00d; Deny</option>
  <option value="1">&#xf00c; Accept</option>
  <option value="3">&#xf256; Reject</option>
  <option value="4">&#xf040; Accounting</option>
</select>
```

In Chrome it works fine, but Firefox doesn't render the icons when you open the select, like you can see here:

[image: HTML select different rendering in FF57 and Chrome63]

Is Firefox missing that feature or is there something I can do with CSS to solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Show us code...

Comment: No. Firefox has that feature. Show your code

Comment: can you provide the full code, from my experience it's better to Unicode value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FontAwesome doesn't display in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032426/fontawesome-doesnt-display-in-firefox)

Comment: Does FontAwesome display correctly elsewhere on the page, i.e. in its expected <i> elements.

Comment: I've read the answer mentioned above and it says that "Firefox only allows cross-domain linking of fonts if the server the font is on sends the right CORS headers". I'll save the font files locally and I'll try again to see if it works. I'll tell the results in a bit. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @MrLister: yes, all the icons used in the web page display correctly in every browser. It's only when I expand the select that they are not showing.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use the non-FontAwesome versions of those characters. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/21uyq1vx/3/

Comment: As an update, I stored the Font Awesome bundle locally to see if Firefox had any trouble with cross-domain linking of fonts but it didn't make any difference. So, I've used the code you wrote on Fiddle and it works in all browsers, so I'm happy with it, thanks!