# Not able to display the font awesome icon from folder

Tags: css, html, font-awesome

I am using font awesome icon but I am not able to display the font awesome icon. I store the font awesome CSS file inside my main folder and added the path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css">
```

but still not able to display.

Then I added whole URL

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

then icon properly displaying.
 Please help me why I am not able to use font awesome from my root folder? Please check the below image.
I am getting output

[image]

[image]

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css">
<!--     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

After adding all fa package then it's working. Check image
[image]

Comment: Which browser? If it's Firefox, maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032426/fontawesome-doesnt-display-in-firefox

Comment: I am using firefox latest one. even It also not working in chrome

Comment: Don't forget to download the whole fa package especially the font files.

Comment: Did you just download and include the css file? Perhaps you haven't included the fonts?

Comment: @Stickers, Yes You are right, Now it's working. There is some packaging issue. I download all the file from font awesome site and added. And it's working. Thanks for the help.