# Fontawesome firefox - 200 instead of 304 and locked

Tags: firefox, font-awesome

All fonts I use on my web page are in the same directory.
For some reasons in Firefox, the font fa-brands-400.woff2 is locked and there is a 200 response when for others fonts there are 304 response.

[image]

In Chrome, icons are displayed correclty.
To resolve the problem, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032426/fontawesome-doesnt-display-in-firefox) without success.

I talked to my server asdministrator who told me he did not see a CORS matter.

Someone has got an idea ?

Comment: The different 200 and 304 response headers should be immaterial (it is just a difference in if the font gets cached or not). What do you mean by the woff2 being "locked"? It would be helpful if you supplied enough detail for this error to be reproduced.

Comment: After a better search, actually, I saw all fonts are locked "Bloqué" on the right top of the image and all fonts are not loaded. This plugin works perfectly when I installed it on another server with different domain name. If it´s not a CORS matter, it seems to be linked to a server problem but I don´t know which one.